# View.jsp not showing with portlet-class set

Tags: liferay, portlet, liferay-6

I am able to make a new portlet, but when I change the class view.jsp no longer renders. No errors in my log.

How do I make a custom MVCPortlet display the standard view.jsp in liferay?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you modified the `portlet-class` in `portlet.xml` appropriately? If so, you need to call `super.render(renderRequest, renderResponse);` in your class's `render` method.